# JQuery AJAX response handling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Probably some simple derp but I just can't figure this out, I'm using almost identical code in a different solution and it works.

Javascript:

```
$('#drop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login').slideToggle(1000);
});

$('#sub').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#info').html('<img src="img/load.gif" />')
    $.post('login.php', {user: document.getElementById('user').value, pass: document.getElementById('pass').value}, function(response) {
        if (response == 'ok')
        {
            $('#login').slideUp(500);
            $('#info').html('');
            $('#joocy').html('<img src="img/load.gif" />').load('manage.php');
        }
        else if (response == 'error')
        {
            $('#info').html('Invalid user/pass');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'ok';
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

Response is being sent back but the if-clause isn't catching it. typeof() returns string.

EDIT:
    else if (response === 'error ') // notice the space in the string

This works, can anyone explain why the space is appended to the returnstring?

SOLVED: There was a space after PHP closing tag. Thanks for your time everyone! :)

Comment: what does the response var return, and what does the if clause not do? Returns false always?

Comment: Returns ok or error as expected and if-clause returns false.

Comment: you are missing a semi-colon after `$('#info').html('<img src="img/load.gif" />')`

Comment: try putting alert or console.log statements in your success functoin to see what is being returned

Comment: do you get "error" in response everytime?
if it is the case then there must be a problem with database operations only..

Comment: alert(response) prints out ok/error, database works fine. The problem is the if-clause isn't catching either. Updated OP.

Comment: You should provide the rest of the PHP file (especially after the `else { echo 'error'; }`) since a whitespace character after the PHP close tag (`?>`)might be sent along with the text.

Comment: I know this isn’t what you’re after, but you could make your life a lot easier if you would have your server respond with a proper response code and use jQuery's response handlers `error` and `success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a space after the closing '?>' tag in your php script. Try either removing all whitespace after, or the closing tag altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the output contains other characters like e.g. a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
What does

```
$.post('login.php', {user: document.getElementById('user').value, pass: document.getElementById('pass').value}, function(response) {
    if (response == 'ok')
    {
        $('#login').slideUp(500);
        $('#info').html('');
        $('#joocy').html('<img src="img/load.gif" />').load('manage.php');
    }
    else if (response == 'error')
    {
        $('#info').html('Invalid user/pass');
    }
    var tmpText = "" + response.length + ": ";
    for(var tmpI=0; tmpI<response.length; tmpI++) {
        tmpText += response.charCodeAt(tmpI) + " ";
    }
    $("<fieldset></fieldset>").text(tmpText).appendTo("#info");
});
```

print?

Answer (score 0):

may the additional  space is added from the `php` side of the code, you can use `trim`

```
if($.trim(response)==='error')
{
 //
}
```